# What's the reward for killing Alira, Oak, and Kraityn?

Tags: path-of-exile

So now that I've made it into Act 2, I've been given a quest to kill three bandit leaders, Alira, Oak, and Kraityn.

I've just managed to make it to Alira, who has presented me with a conundrum: if I help her, she'll give me +40 Mana.  Oak gives +40 Life.  Whereas I have absolutely no idea what the old man will give me for killing all three.

Is the reward for slaying all three bandit leaders worth as much as this pretty significant jump in Mana?

Comment: Do note, the passive increases to health and mana are furthered by nodes that increase the respective attributes, so these will be much higher by end game, and should definitely factor into your decision.

Comment: @SadlyNot Why the combined value? You can only choose one of them.

Comment: @SaintWacko Yeah I worded that totally wrong. Just compare each reward to the value you can get from a passive point. I think the resistances are very valuable because of the resistance loss when you increase difficulty, and the rest is up to you.

Comment: Kripparian has [a good video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuFdvi3khlo) on the topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you kill all three of them, you will be rewarded with two passive skill points.

Answer (score 26):

Regardless of difficulty, if you kill all three bandits, you will receive one passive point. The reward for siding with a Bandit differs based on the difficulty. Who you side with can change in each difficulty. If you side with Oak in normal you are not limited to only choosing Oak again in cruel or merciless.

#### Normal Difficulty

- Alira - Permanent increase of 60 Mana
- Oak - Permanent increase of 40 Health
- Kraityn - Permanent increase of 10% to all elemental resistances

#### Cruel Difficulty

- Alira -   Permanent increase of 5% cast speed
- Oak - Permanent increase of 16% to physical damage
- Kraityn - Permanent increase of 8% to attack speed

#### Merciless Difficulty

- Alira - Permanent increase of maximum power charge by one
- Oak - Permanent increase of maximum endurance charge by one
- Kraityn - Permanent increase of maximum frenzy charge by one

([Source](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Deal_with_the_Bandits))

Comment: This is out of date as of v3.0.

Answer (score 21):

Although @Domocus was correct at the time of writing, as of the [3.0 expansion](https://www.pathofexile.com/oriath) these rewards have changed.  There is now only a single playthrough (rather than three separate playthroughs at different difficulties), which results in each character completing the bandit quest only once.

The rewards for doing so are:

- **Help Alira**:  5 mana regen/sec, +20% global crit multi, +15% to all elemental resistances.
- **Help Kraityn**:  6% increased attack and cast speed, 10% chance to avoid elemental ailments, 6% increased movement speed.
- **Help Oak**:  1% of life regenerated/sec, 2% phys damage reduction, 20% increased phys damage.
- **Kill all**:  2 skill points.

The details of this quest can also be viewed on [the game's wiki](https://www.poewiki.net/wiki/Deal_with_the_Bandits).

Comment: Note: you can only pick one of them to help.